# Excel VBA Error: Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined. Calling a Sub in another sheet/module

Tags: excel, vba

When the Quote_Button_EmailToBeth() Sub is run, it throws the error"

> Compile error: Sub or Function not defined"

and highlights the line that calls the Sub named "EmailToBeth_Unprotect".

As far as I understand, it is actually defined, but in another sheet module:

[image]

I originally thought it might be due to the underscore in the Sub name, but removing them doesn't change the error.  I also know some people will scream that I'm putting code in the sheet/module rather than an actual module.  But I don't think that is the source of the error - correct me if that's wrong.

The "EmailToBeth_Unprotect" Sub call is being made from the sheet/module called "Quote".  The actual Sub is in the "EmailToBeth" sheet/module.  I sure thought you could call things across different modules.

Edit: It works after moving it to the same sheet/module.  But putting everything in one gigantic module will be disorderly with Subs not being logically grouped together with like functions.  So how do you call a Sub in a different module?

Any advice?   Thanks.

Comment: It's not so much "a sub in a different module" as "a sub in a *document* module", or more precisely, "a sub in any *class* module with a VB_PredeclaredId attribute set to True". If you have a not-private sub procedure in a standard module (like any of these Module1-Module4 modules), then you can invoke it from anywhere in the project by name, like you did.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't think that is the source of the error - correct me if that's wrong.

Yes it is wrong becuase `EmailToBeth_Unprotect` is not visible to your other module. To use it, prefix it with the relevant sheet codename. I would recommend reading [Code Module And Code Names](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/codemods.htm).

Here is an example.

```
'~~> In Sheet1 Module
Sub SampleA()
    Sheet2.SampleB
End Sub

'~~> In Sheet2 Module
Sub SampleB()
    Msgbox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

Similarly, if `EmailToBeth_Unprotect` is in `Quote` then you can call it using `Quote.EmailToBeth_Unprotect`. If it is in `EmailToBeth` then call it using `EmailToBeth.EmailToBeth_Unprotect`.